# С каких символов должен состоять пароль пользователя mysql?

Tags: mysql

В доках ничего не нашел. Может кто подскажет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и любой пароль, из любых символов.

[Здесь](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html) искали?

Comment: здесь не искал, но не вижу там подобной информации. Можешь показать пожалуйста.

Comment: Для шифрования пароля используетс функция PASSWORD();

Т.е. если вы добавляете пользователя не через CREATE USER, а прямым insert в таблицу mysql.user, то `Password` = PASSWORD('Ваш пароль')

Comment: и здесь указана, с каких символов должен состоять пароль?

Comment: Ответ: из ЛЮБЫХ